# LINQ to XML row with two attributes

Tags: c#, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

I have a problem. Im trying to get rows, which contains cols. To filter them, I want to check two attributes and values, then, they should return third col.

For example:
XML code sample:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<teryt>
<catalog name="TERC" type="all" date="2015-01-01">
<row>
<col name="WOJ">02</col>
<col name="POW"/>
<col name="GMI"/>
<col name="RODZ"/>
<col name="NAZWA">DOLNOŚLĄSKIE</col>
<col name="NAZDOD">województwo</col>
<col name="STAN_NA">2015-01-01</col>
</row>
<row>
<col name="WOJ">02</col>
<col name="POW">01</col>
<col name="GMI"/>
<col name="RODZ"/>
<col name="NAZWA">bolesławiecki</col>
<col name="NAZDOD">powiat</col>
<col name="STAN_NA">2015-01-01</col>
</row>
<row>
<col name="WOJ">02</col>
<col name="POW">01</col>
<col name="GMI">01</col>
<col name="RODZ">1</col>
<col name="NAZWA">Bolesławiec</col>
<col name="NAZDOD">gmina miejska</col>
<col name="STAN_NA">2015-01-01</col>
</row>
<row>
<col name="WOJ">02</col>
<col name="POW">01</col>
<col name="GMI">02</col>
<col name="RODZ">2</col>
<col name="NAZWA">Bolesławiec</col>
<col name="NAZDOD">gmina wiejska</col>
<col name="STAN_NA">2015-01-01</col>
</row>
<row>
<col name="WOJ">02</col>
<col name="POW">01</col>
<col name="GMI">03</col>
<col name="RODZ">2</col>
<col name="NAZWA">Gromadka</col>
<col name="NAZDOD">gmina wiejska</col>
<col name="STAN_NA">2015-01-01</col>
</row>
```

And for now Im trying to do this using this code:

```
public static IEnumerable<XElement> ZwrocNumerWojewodztwa(IEnumerable<XElement> rows, String value1, String value2)
{
    return rows
        .Where(row => row.Elements("col")
        .Any(col =>
         col.Attributes("name").Any(attr => attr.Value.Equals("WOJ"))
                && col.Value.Equals(value1) && (col.Attributes("name").Any(attr => attr.Value.Equals("POW"))
                && col.Value.Equals(value2))));
}
```

When I delete second col.Attributes("name").Any(...), the code works brilliant. What do I do wrong?

Then I have to take out from code cols "NAZWA", any tips?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you want:

```
return rows
    .Where(row =>
        row.Elements("col").Any(col =>
            col.Attributes("name").Any(attr => attr.Value.Equals("WOJ")) &&
            col.Value.Equals(value1)) &&

        row.Elements("col").Any(col =>
            col.Attributes("name").Any(attr => attr.Value.Equals("POW")) &&
            col.Value.Equals(value2)));
```

Link to working code: https://dotnetfiddle.net/9aJOCV

Answer (score 0):

This issue is you are looking for rows which have a single column attribute set both to "POW" **AND** "WOJ".  Switch it to **OR**.